# how to use retrieve and use setting value to connect to adatabase

Tags: c#

i am developing window application and i want the user of the app can change the connection string so i create aform to save connection string to setting and able to retrieve it but the problem is how to use this setting

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    var serv = Properties.Settings.Default.server; 
    var db = Properties.Settings.Default.database; 
    var userid = Properties.Settings.Default.userid; 
    var pass = Properties.Settings.Default.password; 

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=serv;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=userid password=pass"); 
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE username='" + txtUsername.Text + "' and password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'", conn); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + serv.ToString() + ";Initial Catalog=" + db.ToString() + ";User ID=" + userid.ToString() + ";password= " + pass.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your connection string in the `App.config/Web.config`, it will make it that much easier to alter later on if need be.

Also remember to always make use of the `using` statement when working with `SqlConnection` in general.

**For example:**

In the `App.config/Web.config` add the following:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="myConnectionString" value="Data Source=serv;Initial Catalog=db;User ID=userid password=pass" />
</appSettings>
```

Then you can easily access it anywhere in your project:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myConnectionString"]))
{
  using(SqlCommand sqlCommandConn = new SqlCommand(InsertStatement))
  {
    sqlCommandConn.Connection = conn;
    //TODO: Open connection, Execute queries...
  }
}
```

**Note**

You can alter these settings via code as well if you wish:

```
   private void UpdateConfig(string key, string value)
    {
        var configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        configFile.AppSettings.Settings[key].Value = value;

        configFile.Save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from your code snippet, the connection string value is just a `string` that you are passing to the `SqlConnection` constructor, so for your case you could pull the value at runtime and load that value dynamically.

While *it is possible* to manipulate the `app.config` file which does hold connection string values, I typically prefer to manipulate secondary files. A better option could be to use a secondary file in `XML` for example and preform CRUD like operations on it as your users change their connection strings. At runtime, you can pull their specific connection string value and load it into the constructor as your doing above. A sample XML structure could be as follows:

```
<connections>
  <connection userID="12345">Data Source=servA;Initial Catalog=db123;User ID=jSmith password=pass1</connection>
  <connection userID="43532">Data Source=servB;Initial Catalog=db456;User ID=rJSmith password=abc321</connection>
</connections>
```

If all that is changing is the user, pass, catalog, and datasource values and the remainder of the connection string is static, you could just store these individual values as opposed to the entire connection string and then inject those dynamically to build the connection string at runtime.

Reading the XML is not difficult when using something like LINQ to XML which would allow you to query the XML file and get a specific connection string by the `userID` field. A good reference for LINQ to XML is at the following: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx